# T-SQL parse XML data into single line

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, parsing

I have XML saved into a column in a table as type `nvarchar`. Now I need to parse data from that `xml`. I do

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(XML, columnX).value('(chatTranscript/message/msgText/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

as chat but I get only first value. How do I extract all into single line? XML can be long, depends on chat length.

I need to get `userNick` and then `msgText` and loop it till the end. Something like this:

```
userX:Hello<>userY:How are you;
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chatTranscript startAt="2020-07-30T11:00:12Z" sessionId="......">
    <newParty userId="......" timeShift="0" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
        <userInfo personId="" userNick="userX"/>
    </newParty>
    <message userId="..." timeShift="12" visibility="ALL" eventId="9">
        <msgText msgType="text">Hello</msgText>
    </message>
    <newParty userId="..." timeShift="15" visibility="ALL" eventId="10">
        <userInfo userNick="userY"/>
    </newParty>
    <message userId="..." timeShift="29" visibility="ALL" eventId="12">
        <msgText treatAs="NORMAL">how are you?</msgText>
    </message>
    <partyLeft userId="..." timeShift="36" visibility="ALL" eventId="13" askerId="...">
        <reason code="1">left with request to close if no agents</reason>
    </partyLeft>
    <partyLeft userId="..." timeShift="36" visibility="ALL" eventId="14" askerId="...">
        <reason code="4">removed by other party</reason>
    </partyLeft>
</chatTranscript>
```

Comment: *"I have xml saved into column in a table as nvarchar"* if it's XML why are you using `nvarchar` and not the `xml` datatype?

Comment: babbon,  while asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: babbon, why do you use an Element <msgText>? Why is the text of a message not just included as the text of <message>? Your task could be easier if you would redesign your xml schema. If you would use a more generic element and use a more specific type, queries might be easier. E.g. <ChatEvent type="UserJoin"/><ChatEvent type="message"/><ChatEvent type="UserLeft"/>... Also I wonder about the required sort order. Is timeshift or eventId relevant for ordering the required output?

Comment: I cannot change the column type nor the schema of xml. I have what I have now I need to extract data from it. Table I have contains id (int) and columnX (nvarchar) that is xml content. Now I need to select from columnX so it would be easy to read without tags and useless information. If I do: select id, CONVERT(XML, [columnX]).value('(chatTranscript/newParty/userInfo/@userNick)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') + ': ' + CONVERT(XML, [columnX]).value('(chatTranscript/message/msgText/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') from tableX I am getting "userX: Hello". But I need whole conversation like that in one line.

Comment: @babboon What if there are more messages? What's the desire output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need code to do this cleanly.  Trying to do what you are asking will be super messy T-SQL.  I'd recommend parsing the xml in code to generate what you want based on that xml.  You could also create a CLR function using code so that you can create a SQL function to do this.  You can do some amazing things with XQuery and T-SQL, but sometimes it just gets to messy.  For xml manipulation all within the database, CLR functions are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_parse_chat_xml] (@xml XML) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @n INT, @content NVARCHAR(MAX), @userId NVARCHAR(200), @userNick1 NVARCHAR(200), @userNick2 NVARCHAR(200), @userNickX NVARCHAR(200)
    SET @n = 1 
    SET @userId = @xml.value('(chatTranscript/newParty/@userId)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    SET @userNick1 = @xml.value('(chatTranscript/newParty/userInfo/@userNick)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    SET @userNick2 = @xml.value('(chatTranscript/newParty/userInfo/@userNick)[2]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    WHILE DATALENGTH(@xml.value('(chatTranscript/message/msgText/text())[sql:variable("@n")][1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))>0 
        BEGIN        
            IF @userId = @xml.value('(chatTranscript/message/@userId)[sql:variable("@n")][1]', 'nvarchar(max)') 
                SET @userNickX = @userNick1
            else 
                SET @userNickX = @userNick2 
            SET @content = concat(@content, ' <> ', @userNickX, ': ', @xml.value('(chatTranscript/message/msgText/text())[sql:variable("@n")][1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))
            SET @n = @n + 1
        END
    RETURN @content
END
```